# can a php variable contain a 'array' and 'sort_asc' to be used in array_multisort?

Tags: php, variables, array-multisort

Essentially I would like to create a variable with a string to be used later in array_multisort. Is this possible? E.g.

```html
<?php

$variable = "$array['name'], SORT_ASC";

array_multisort($variable, $rows);
```

I realise that it's got something to do with the SORT_ASC being constant but I wouldn't know why.I also realise there might be a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: *there might be a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do* And what are you trying to do?

Comment: You'd be better storing it as an array `$variable = ['name', SORT_ASC];` and using `array_multisort($rows, array_column($rows, $variable[0]), $variable[1]);`

Comment: @Rizier123 = dynamic control over the array_multisort parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a multidimensional array for that purpose:

```
<?php

$examp = array("array" => $array,
          "SORT" => SORT_ASC);

if(isset($examp)){
    array_multisort($examp["array"], $examp["SORT"]);
}

?>
```

Comment: that is what I wanted to post. Naming the array elements makes the code more clear. Especially when you look at it again in a few months time :)

Comment: Don't think so, array_multisort would show a warning asking for an array in first paramenter.

Comment: Ok so given that, can I throw an if(isset) statement inside array_multisort to resolve a possible null issue?

Comment: Yes, of course. let me change the answer to show you.

Comment: Remeber, if you find this answer helpful, please select it as correct to help others.

Comment: I shall as soon as I'm able to get it going :)!

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to read array code. I get error:     Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in... ?

Comment: Working :)! Added 'array' so now looks like:  'array("array" => $array,
          "SORT" => SORT_ASC);'

Comment: Yes, of course. I corrected in my answer. Glad it helped ;)